# vbScript ignore many blank spaces after split

Tags: vbscript, split, hp-uft

When I split a string with many spaces, is there a way to skip blank spaces?

Example string below:

```
Lorem                            ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
             adipiscing elit. Morbi cursus quam sapien, sed ultricies diam vestibulum ac.
Morbi                    luctus nisl eleifend                    mi tincidunt, 
sed vehicula magna lobortis.
```

When split, the array contains many positions of  " " (blank spaces)

```
[0] Lorem
[1] " "
[2] " "
[3] " "
[4] " "
[5] Ipsum
```

So, is there a way to skip this blank spaces and get something like this?

```
[0] Lorem
[1] Ipsum
[3] dolor
```

Here's my code:

```
strTmp = split(tmpstr," ")
For each text in strTmp
'Here I validate other things
  If InStr(x,textToFind) Then
    print "text found"
  Else
    print "not found"
  End If
Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the way is to process the string before splitting it.

**Sample Code**

```
varStr = "Lorem                            ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur             adipiscing elit. Morbi cursus quam sapien, sed ultricies diam vestibulum ac. Morbi                    luctus nisl eleifend                    mi tincidunt, sed vehicula magna lobortis"

' this is what you are getting right now
arrStr = Split(varStr, " ")

Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With objRegEx
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = "\s+" 'matches any whitespace character
    varStr1 = objRegEx.Replace(varStr, "¬")
End With
Set objRegEx = Nothing

' this is what you want
arrStr1 = Split(varStr1, "¬")
```

I have first stripped all spaces and replaced it with a single ¬ which will act as a delim when I split the string later on.

Answer (score 1):

Can do a loop on the string, and replace double spaces with single spaces

```
Do Until InStr(text, "  ") = 0
        text= Replace(text, "  ", " ")
    Loop
```

Comment: I don't know why the downvote. It was the solution I was about to suggest because it is very simple. I upvoted you to compensate.

Comment: Wasn't me, I has no enough reputation to give down or up votes

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
If trim(text) <> "" Then
Else
End if
```

Or

```
If len(trim(text)) > 0 Then
Else
End if
```

Comment: isnt trim for outside the string only?

Comment: After you do the split and when you loop through the array items, you can ignore the empty ones using this. If you do not want the empty array items itself, then you may try to get rid of the extra spaces before the split.